# Two namespaces with the same object name

Tags: c#

I have two namespaces:

System.Numerics and UnityEngine

Both have the type `Vector3`.

So now when ever i want to use it i have to declare which namespace before it. Like this:

```
protected struct CVN
{
    public Complex h;
    public UnityEngine.Vector2 d;
    public UnityEngine.Vector3 n;
}
```

Is there any way to define that i only want `Vector3` from one namespace so i don't have to always type `NameSpaceHere.Vector3` every single time ?

Or am i stuck with the tedious nature of stating the namespace every time. Especially since i only need the `Complex` type from Numerics its quite annoying.

Comment: Maybe use `Numerics.Complex` and `using UnityEngine;`?

Comment: Well then i have to state Numerics every where i use Complex so that just switches the problem to other type :P

Comment: Where ever you want to user `vector2` and `vector3` from `UnityEngine` namespace, you need to declare `using Vector2 = UnityEngine.Verctor2;` and `using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3` at the top of the class file.

Comment: If you were using more than one type from Numerics, and especially if you were using similarly named types from both, I'd have said stick with it despite more typing, just to make it crystal clear which type you mean in each location. (For the benefit of future readers, like yourself in 6 months time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need from `System.Numerics` is `Complex`, then:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Complex = System.Numerics.Complex;
```

At the top of your file, without `using System.Numerics;` should do it.
This is an **alias**.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap  the using directive of the wanted class in the namespace of your current class rather than putting it outside.
Consider this example

```
namespace System.Numerics
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

```
using System.Numeric;

namespace ConsoleApplication24
{
    using UnityEngine; // inside the namespace
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass xx = new MyClass(); // from UnitEngine instead of System.Numeric
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, and I didn't know that it had this behaviour. +1 (I had to test it in order to be convinced though ^^)