# For C# Project, how to raise a custom build error if someone tries to use specific method from framework class?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

For a C# Project, I want to include a build step or something integrated in project that should raise build error if any developer is trying to use a specific method from framework classes, instead I want developers to use extension method for same. However I want to impose this as the compile time error. As an example, for a name sake I want developer on given project not to use string.Intern, instead should always use string.SpecialIntern. What are different ways to achieve this? I tried to use Roslyn-code-analysis but could not really write working rule for this, so I am not sure if tha'ts the right solution to this problem. Can someone guide me in details how to solve this with some examples?

Comment: i think the best you can do is to add  an obsolete attribute

Comment: Why don't you simply redirect the call to the extension method?

Comment: @JohnB as I said it's from framework class, as an example I cannt mark string.Intern as an Obsolete

Comment: @Shawn how to dynamically redirect call to extension method? can you provide example to do so at Runtime or compile time ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something you could accomplish with a custom code analyzer. I haven't tried it yet, but I believe it is possible to write your own analyzers.

This article from Microsoft claims to tell you how to do it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2017

Here's a direct link to the tutorial referenced in that article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to achieve what you're trying to do.

However, a solution would be to simply call the extension method.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool DoStuff(this Class stuff)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Class
{
    public bool DontCallMe()
    {
        return this.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

```
Class myClass = new Class();
myClass.DontCallMe();
```

Obviously, that only works if you can change the code of your class (which I suppose you aren't able to)

If that method is marked as virutal, you could create a Wrapper-Class which overrides that method.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool DoStuff(this Class stuff)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Class : Base
{
    public override bool DontCallMe()
    {
        return this.DoStuff();
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual bool DontCallMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Another approach would be to do what I described in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822112/two-namespaces-with-the-same-object-name/54822260#54822260) post.